# How to select (i.e. second) a group in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

my column look like this:

```
delta
delta
alpha
alpha
alpha
gamma
gamma
gamma
```

I'd like to group it and order. So it will result with:

```
1. alpha
2. delta
3. gamma
```

And that's still easy.
Now, the point is to tell SQL "Show me the second group", not knowing what data we will actually have there. In other words - not naming the group, just by a number.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` analytic function for that:

```
select your_col
  from (select your_col,
               row_number() over (order by your_col) as rn
          from your_table
         group by your_col)
 where rn = 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works. However my query is actually a bit more complicated - it calls also a couple other columns (from the same table) and takes them also for grouping.
So I didn't succeed with implementing it..

`code
select ALPHA
  from (select ALPHA
               row_number() over (order by ALPHA) as rn, BETA, sum(TETA+GAMMA), count(OMEGA)
          from v_analysisview
         group by ALPHA, prodlevel3, nominal)
where rn = 2
code`

Comment: @Andy: Consider asking a new question for that with all the relevant details.  If your next question is as clear as this one, you'll get an answer in no time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advise. As you may guess, I'm quite new here ;)